# What is the range of Scikit-Learn's IsolationForest decision_function scores?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection

Scikit-Learn's [**IsolationForest**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) class has a method `decision_function` that returns the anomaly scores of the input samples. However, the documentation does not state what the possible range of these scores is, and only states that "the lower [the score], the more abnormal."

Edit: after reading jmunsch's comment I looked at the source code again and here is my updated guess:
If the exponent in the [**scores formula**](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py#L267-L272) is always negative, then scores will always be between 0 and 1, which would mean the returned range is [-0.5, 0.5] since `0.5 - scores` is returned by the method. But I'm not certain if the exponent would always be negative.

Comment: when in doubt look at the source : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py#L267-L272

Comment: @jmunsch I forgot to mention in my question that I did look at the source, but it wasn't apparent to me what the range would be. If the exponent is always negative, then scores will always be between 0 and 1, which would mean the range is [-0.5, 0.5]. But I'm not certain if the exponent would always be negative.

Answer (score 5):

**In Scikit-Learn's IsolationForest the decision_function returns values in the range of [-0.5, 0.5] where -.5 is the most anomalous.**

*Or so I believe and have never seen evidence otherwise.* The documentation for Scikit-Learn's IsolationForest references a paper [Isolation-based Anomaly Detection by Liu et al.](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/tkdd11.pdf) where equation 2 defines the anomaly score. In the paper the anomaly score ranges between 0 and 1, where 1 is most anomalous. In the [scores function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/ensemble/iforest.py#L267-L272) you reference on line 267 the variable depths.mean(axis=1) corresponds to E(h(x)) and _average_path_length(self.max_samples_)) corresponds to c(psi) in the paper. Thus on line 272 when the function returns 1 minus the score we get the bounds of [-0.5, 0.5].

**Edit/Bonus:** 
The predict method of isolation forest effectively is just comparing the decision_function values to a threshold that is stored in `model.threshold_`. So after calling the model's predict method on some data the anomalous items are the same items that meet the criteria:`model.decision_function(data) < model.threshold_`.